# How can I make this grunge texture (Old Cymbal)

Tags: modeling, texturing

I saw a drum cymbal model on Blenderswap,( https://www.blendswap.com/blend/23008 )and wanted to improve the appearance of the cymbal. I have tried 2 methods, one UV mapping an image of a cymbal texture, and the other method making a circle with ridges (But results to lot of geometry).

My texture of the modelled circle, has a bronze texture using BlenderKit. Is there a way to combine some grunge into the texture to make it appear that the cymbal has aged?

Old Cymbal reference image:

[image]

Also the image from Blenderswap, has some sculpting applied to it.

I also tried sculpting making holes, but it was a tedious task, and not all sculpting was correctly in place, and the subdivision I added causes my PC to lag very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You would like to overlay the image texture onto the metal material, resulting in a more realistic appearance?

Comment: Yes, blending 2 textures on my cymbal mesh. Because the texture I used is too generic and clean. And also if my modelling is correct making, and if there's a better way to model a cymbal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I quickly modelled a cymbal (upper half of sphere scaled along the Z axis, with an additional translation for the dome), and applied a bronze material from BlenderKit:

[image]

I then replaced the Roughness map the material shipped with, with the image you provided:

[image]
[image]

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

Not sure if you know this already, but for completeness' sake: the Roughness texture is responsible for the amount of reflectivity of your material. Scratches and other surface imperfections (like corrosion) will roughen up a surface, and diffuse the light it reflects.
The image you posted is of course not really suitable for this function, as it contains a watermark, has specular reflections (seen in the image above as the brightest and darkest spots), lumps all types of roughness into the same image (for more realism you might want to treat different kinds of imperfection differently), is a picture of a 3-dimensional object, resulting in a warped projection, &c.
For better roughness maps you can search online for "scratch maps" or "surface imperfections maps". To start with, [here](https://www.artstation.com/marketplace/p/3yAy/free-surface-imperfections-pack) is a free pack, and you can find a few free ones [here](https://www.poliigon.com/textures/surface-imperfections) and [here](https://ambientcg.com/list?category=&date=&createdUsing=&basedOn=&q=imperfections&method=&type=Material&sort=Popular).

---

Additionally, since you mention your computer struggling with this model, you could bake the (what I assume are sculpted) curves into a normal map, which can in turn be applied to a simpler mesh with fewer polygons.
This process involves quite a few steps, and goes beyond your main question here, so please see [this excellent Blender Guru tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw) to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proposition that uses the image texture you provide, use it in the *Base Color* and in the *Roughness* input of the *Principled BSDF*, set the *Metallic* value to 1:

[image]